# RCPP Function for Generation Random Walk in 4 Directions

Tags: c++, r, math, rcpp

I am trying to generate a Function called StepstoShop which will generate a Matrix of n*2 representing an x and y co-ordinate. The directions allowed are only North, South, East and West (No Diagonal movement allowed)

This is the code I have developed so far

```
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]


NumericMatrix StepstoShop(double Steps){

    NumericMatrix SampleGen(Steps,2);
    int n=SampleGen.size();
    int colnum= rand()%1;



for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
      { SampleGen(i,colnum)=(rand()%3)-1;
      }

return SampleGen;
}
```

I've tried to index a random number allocation between 0 and 1 to the column in a for loop through rows, to get the desired outcome of the 4 directions
(0,1) (1,0) (-1,0) (0,-1), however I am getting a mixture in 8 directions.

Any Guidance, would be much appreciated

Thanks

I've retrospectively included R code to illustrate what I was trying to recreate

```
  # compute path
  n <- 1000
  rw <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = n)
  # generate the indices to set the deltas
  indx <- cbind(seq(n), sample(c(1, 2), n, TRUE))

  # now set the values
  rw[indx] <- sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE)
  # cumsum the columns
  rw[,1] <- cumsum(rw[, 1])
  rw[, 2] <- cumsum(rw[, 2])

  plot(0,type="n",xlab="x",ylab="y",main="Random Walk Simulation In Two 
  Dimensions",col=1:10,xlim=range(-10,15),ylim=range(-40,40))

  # use 'segments' to color each path
  segments(head(rw[, 1], -1)
  , head(rw[, 2], -1)
  , tail(rw[, 1], -1)
  , tail(rw[, 2], -1)
  , col = rainbow(nrow(rw) -1)  # a range of colors
  )

  end<-cbind(-10,30)
  start<-cbind(0,0)

  points(start,pch=16,col="green", cex = 3)
  points(end,pch=16,col="red", cex = 3)
```

The idea is to iterate this code 100,000 times and calculate the probability of reaching the endpoint

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix StepstoShop(double Steps){

  IntegerVector possible_x = IntegerVector::create(0, 1, -1, 0);
  IntegerVector possible_y = IntegerVector::create(1, 0, 0, -1);
  IntegerMatrix SampleGen(Steps, 2);
  int ind;

  for (int i = 0; i < Steps; i++) {
    ind = R::runif(0, 4);
    SampleGen(i, 0) = possible_x[ind];
    SampleGen(i, 1) = possible_y[ind];
  }

  return SampleGen;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @F.Prive .... Could you expand on exactly what `R::runif(0,4)` is it returning an int which corresponds to the indices of the two vectors?

Comment: You want an index 0, 1, 2, or 3. So, you generate a value between 0 and 4 that is truncated when converted to int.

Comment: @PD9154 `R::runif(0,4)` returns a `double` within `(0, 4)` which is implicitly converted to an integer in `[0, 1, 2, 3]` by C++. One could make this explicit with `floor`.

Comment: Maybe would we more explicit to use `sample`.